# Data validation list, combo box, or active X combo box in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel

Started with a data validation list and I like that it is in the cell where I want the data to appear. Tried combo box and active X combo box and don't like that they do not reside in the cell. This is very different than Access. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

My named range (Employee) is `A4:C100`, 3 columns, with headings `Title`, `MI`, and `LN` on a sheet named "Emp".

My form location is C6. I wanted to be able to show 3 columns and end up with data from the three columns. For example, Officer J. Doe.

Currently I am using data validation list entering data into one column as Doe, J., Officer and it works. The list can be long and I will need it to be in alphabetical order.

Is this the best way or am I confused with combo box and active X combo box?

Comment: Why not Access? And by Validation do you mean you want your form in C6 (cells? userform?) to move data and place it appropriately in the list? Sorting it as it is entered?

Comment: It has to be in Excel. In Excel you can create a list using data validation. It puts a down arrow in the cell where you want a list. It is limiting so the range can only be one column. Combo box and/or active X combo box does not reside in the cells where I want the list to appear.  Can you attach examples?  New to forum.

Comment: You can edit your question with code. Just be sure you use the code tags `{}` or ```. If you use form controls and not activeX controls you have a lot of control over how that combobox is populated. Because it is in a sheet and not a user for you have like 95% the functionality of a regular combobox. While they do not reside inside the cell truly you can sort of force the issue and lock them over a cell.

Comment: Hi Brad--how would I lock it over a cell?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to show a combination of all 3 columns in a dropdown list is to concatenate the data in a 4th column e.g. use the following formula in Cell D4

```
=A4&" "&B4&" "&C4
```

...then you can name the range D4:D100. You may wish to hide this column for presentational reasons

Actually, you will probably want to avoid naming the whole range as the bottom cells may be blank/make scrolling more awkward than strictly necessary. I would recommend [dynamic ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm)

The next extension exercise might be to develop your formula to allow for e.g. a missing middlename e.g.

```
=A4&" "&IF(B4<>"",B4&" ","")&C4
```

The above assumes you can sort the data manually. If the data is not being sorted manually, you will need to use VBA e.g. ensure Column D gets completed and the named range created each time a user moves off Sheet("Emp"). You can embed the following code in the Emp sheet...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate

For n = 4 to 100
    If Cells(n, 1) <> "" Then
    Cells(n, 4) = Cells(n, 1) & " " & Cells(n, 2) & " " & Cells(n, 3)
    End If
Next n

Range(Cells(4,4),Cells(100,4)).Sort Key1:=Cells(4,4), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

LastRow = 4

Do Until Cells(LastRow + 1, 4) = ""
LastRow = LastRow + 1
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Employee", RefersTo:=Range(Cells(4,4),Cells(LastRow,4))

End Sub
```

The expressions for sorting/adding range names can be found by recording macros and eliminating code as in this [expert Excel support video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/vba-record-macros.php). Your data validation would refer to 'Employee' which is the range name created in the 4th column

There are a number of assumptions made above such as the idea that all employees have data in the first column and you would need to add logical tests if you do not always have data in all three columns

It may also be that you would prefer to create the Employee range when a user clicks in cell C6 of your form, as this may be more robust. My assumption in using Worksheet_Deactivate is that 'Employee' may be used elsewhere in your spreadsheet

Comment: Hi Ed--I tried concatenate and then my vlookup formulas did not work.  I have two cells on the form that fill-in from Emp table.  Can this forum send attachments?

Comment: Hi Ed-I am not receiving emails when my questions get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Put this code in your worksheet where the comboBox is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim topY As Integer, leftX As Integer

    topY = ComboBox1.top
    leftX = ComboBox1.left

    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Cells(5, 5)
    c.Left = topY 
    c.Top = leftX 
    c.Width = ComboBox1.Width
    c.Height = ComboBox1.Height

End Sub
```

It should keep it locked in place if you move things around. Or you could try it in your `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` event.